# many greater victories vs. many greater victories

Tags: usage

Both A and B have the same meaning, but C is different from A and B, isn’t it? Because ***many*** modifies ***victories*** in C while ***even*** and ***much*** modify ***greater*** in A and B respectively. Am I right about this?

- A : The soccer team has tasted even greater victories this season. ( ○ )
- B : The soccer team has tasted much greater victories this season. ( ○ )
- C : The soccer team has tasted many greater victories this season. ( ○ )

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that *many* modifies *victories* in C while *even* and *much* modify *greater* in A and B respectively, but A and B are not quite equivalent in meaning.

Both A and B imply that the team has some victory we are discussing, and had victories before that. However, they have subtly different senses.

"Even greater victories" implies that the victory under discussion was a great one, but the previous victory was greater, but doesn't imply anything about how much greater.

"Much greater victories" doesn't imply that the victory under discussion was a great one - it might have been a narrow victory, or a victory at a cost. But it does imply that the previous victories were greater than the one under discussion by a lot.